# ipython help functions(?)(??) dosen't describe info properly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

installed IPython version 8.5.0 via conda.

after running '?' in shell this is part of output:

```
  object?   -> Details about 'object'.
  object??  -> More detailed, verbose information about 'object'.
```

so for trying this i also executed:

```
In [5]: len?
Signature: len(obj, /)
Docstring: Return the number of items in a container.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method

In [6]: len??
Signature: len(obj, /)
Docstring: Return the number of items in a container.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

as you see there's no different between two functions result,  while '??' should reference to source code (based on a book I'm reading)  and show more information about object, but it's not happening.

so i think this function isn't working properly, what can i do about it?

[link to book im reading](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/)

Comment: What further information do you think it might be able to give?  `len()` is a built-in function, the source code isn't directly available to you (and isn't written in Python, anyway).  Try this with a function you defined, and you should see the difference between the `?` and `??` options.

Comment: to be more complete, `help()` won't to retrieve code for many builtins because they are written in C and compiled, however, they have extremely good documentation! additionally, `len()` tries a few methods of the object it's called on, rather than doing much work itself! you can see the complete cPython source code here https://github.com/python/cpython

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, `len??` doesn't give the source code because the source code **is not in Python**. It's in C. However, for other functions it will work:

```py
In [1]: import antigravity

In [2]: antigravity.geohash?
Signature: antigravity.geohash(latitude, longitude, datedow)
Docstring:
Compute geohash() using the Munroe algorithm.

>>> geohash(37.421542, -122.085589, b'2005-05-26-10458.68')
37.857713 -122.544543
File:      c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\antigravity.py
Type:      function

In [3]: antigravity.geohash??
Signature: antigravity.geohash(latitude, longitude, datedow)
Source:
def geohash(latitude, longitude, datedow):
    '''Compute geohash() using the Munroe algorithm.

    >>> geohash(37.421542, -122.085589, b'2005-05-26-10458.68')
    37.857713 -122.544543

    '''
    # https://xkcd.com/426/
    h = hashlib.md5(datedow, usedforsecurity=False).hexdigest()
    p, q = [('%f' % float.fromhex('0.' + x)) for x in (h[:16], h[16:32])]
    print('%d%s %d%s' % (latitude, p[1:], longitude, q[1:]))
File:      c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\antigravity.py
Type:      function
```